# Can we use xDB contact to do a Lookup for users

Tags: xdb, contact-facets

Can we use first name in the xDB contact facet and make a search from the UI using an api.
I dont want to fetch all the users and do a for loop and then search for the user name like in each iteration.

Can someone please suggest me a best approach for this. This requirement is for ajax call to fetch all users starting with the text on key press.

Comment: Has any of the provided answers helped you?

Comment: Hi Dmytro, I am checking the recommended solutions. Will update you as soon as I find any.

Answer (score 3):

### API endpoint

There is an api route for that (it is being used by exp. profile in fact):

> [host]/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?**pageSize**=100&**pageNumber**=1&**sort**=visitCount%20desc&match=**john**

This will search for name and email occurances.

### API method

If you want to use your custom controller, you can use the below method from API:

```
CustomerIntelligenceManager.ContactSearchProvider.Find(new ContactSearchParameters())
```

### Content search

In case it is required to use more complex queries you can use analytics index as any other to search. You should use `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Models.IndexedContact` as an Indexable POCO class

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_analytics_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
     var query = context.GetQueryable<IndexedContact>().Where(c=> c.Firstname.Equals("John"));
}
```

Comment: Good idea about using the index. BTW, `ContactSearchProvider` is just another interface to the Analytics index.

Comment: I'd like to add that a contact in Sitecore is not necessarily a user (from membership table). So you would need some mechanism to mark a contact that's also a user. An example of this are contacts that was uploaded using csv file through the list manager

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to create an index on that field to ensure good query performance. Execute this command from the MongoDB console:

```
db.Contacts.ensureIndex({ "Personal.FirstName": 1 }, { "sparse": true })
```

Then you can query the Collection database in your C# code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["analytics"];
var url = new MongoUrl(connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString);
var client = new MongoClient(connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString);
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();

MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(url.DatabaseName);

string searchName = "Meghan";

MongoCursor results =
    database
        .GetCollection("Contacts")
        .Find(Query.Matches("Personal.FirstName", "^" + searchName))
        .SetFields("Personal.FirstName")
        .SetLimit(10);

foreach (BsonDocument r in results)
{
    string firstName = r["Personal"]["FirstName"].AsString;
}
```

Keep in mind that you're getting pretty low-level with this, circumventing the Sitecore API. If the structure of data changes in the future, you'll need to adjust the query.

Also, **never** change contact objects directly.

Comment: At Symposium 2016 they said that they were soon wrapping Mongo/DocumentDB with a layer that we could write apis against. Do you know if they exists in 8.2u2 yet? Maybe it s a 8.3 update. That would help us not having to go directly to Mongo.

Comment: @dnstommy That's not released yet. But yeah, in the future it should become easier to query the database.

Comment: I can not stress the last line of this answer more. Heed the warning. **NEVER** directly edit a contact object. =) Always use available Sitecore API.