# How to get Sitecore User Custom Profile Data in JSON Format?

Tags: user-profile

I Created user with custom fields and in User Manger am able to see user custom fields along with data. Are these fields stored in Mongo Db?

I want to retrieve all the custom user profile data into Json format, please suggest any approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to extract the custom properties. The data is stored in the Core database.

[image: Demo in ISE]

```powershell
$user = Get-User -Id "sitecore\michael"
$data = @{}
foreach($name in $user.Profile.GetCustomPropertyNames()) {
    $data[$name] = $user.Profile.GetCustomProperty($name)
}

$data | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not had to do this before but there are a few options available to you by the looks of things.

1) Use an query against the Mongo DB API similar to this:

```
//Connecting to the Analytics DB
    var driver = Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString("analytics");

    //Building our query
    var builder = new QueryBuilder();
    var filter = builder.And(builder.GTE(_ => _.StartDateTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)), builder.EQ(_ => _.SiteName, siteName.ToLower())); 

    //Retrieving data from the "Interactions" collection
    var interactions = driver.Interactions.FindAs(filter)
```

> http://sitecorepro.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/starting-with-sitecore-analytics.html
>   **or**
>   http://www.nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2016/July/Retrieving-Interactions-Data-from-MongoDB-using-Sitecore-Analytics-API

2) Use Sitecore Experience Extractor :https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor

3) It looks like you could also query contact info via Search like so:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_analytics_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
     var query = context.GetQueryable<IndexedContact>().Where(c=> c.Firstname.Equals("John"));
}
```

> [Can we use xDB contact to do a Lookup for users](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/can-we-use-xdb-contact-to-do-a-lookup-for-users)