# Get contact from xDB without identifier

Tags: xdb

I need to retrieve a contact from xDB, but I don't have that contact's identifier.

Normally I would do it like this:

```
ContactRepository contactRepo = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository;
Contact contact = contactRepo.LoadContactReadOnly(someIdentifier);
```

However, the identifier used in `LoadContactReadOnly` (or in `TryLoadContact`) is unknown.

I do, however, know the value of some of the other facets on the contact.

How can I get a contact (or many contacts) from xDB that has a specific value in a facet other than `Identifier`? For example, get all contacts with a specific email address in the `Emails.Entries.Preferred.SmtpAddress` facet.

Comment: Do you need it in c# so you can do it over and over? Or something like Robo mongo as a one or two off?

Comment: @ChrisAuer C#. I know the Robo 3t (formerly RoboMongo) syntax, but unfortunately that's not transferrable to C#.

Comment: I think I have used this code before. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/can-we-use-xdb-contact-to-do-a-lookup-for-users/4278#4278